# QGIS Stops Working When I Run the PyQGIS Script the second time

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis

QGIS Version - 3.0
I developed a script which creates layers and saves it the to the disk. When I run the script, it runs successfully the first time. But when I run it the second time, QGIS crashes. Can someone help me to figure out what could be the problem?

Here is the script.

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.0", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False) ###
qgs.initQgis() ###

_layer1 = QgsVectorLayer("C:/AR/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/MasterLine.shp", "MASTERLINE", "ogr")
_layer2 = QgsVectorLayer("C:/AR/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/SIGNAL.shp", "SIGNAL", "ogr")
_layer3 = QgsVectorLayer("C:/AR/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/ClearancePoint.shp", "CLEARANCEPOINT", "ogr")

if not _layer1.isValid():
  print("Layer failed to load!")

else:
    print("Layer was loaded successfully!")

if not _layer2.isValid():
  print("Layer failed to load!")

else:
    print("Layer was loaded successfully!")

if not _layer3.isValid():
  print("Layer failed to load!")

else:
    print("Layer was loaded successfully!")

_writer1 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_layer1,"C:/AR/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/MasterLine12.shp",'utf-8',QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(),'ESRI Shapefile')
_writer2 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_layer2,"C:/AR/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/SIGNAL.shp",'utf-8',QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(),'ESRI Shapefile')
_writer3 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_layer3,"C:/AR/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/ClearancePoint.shp",'utf-8',QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(),'ESRI Shapefile')

qgs.exitQgis()

#_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_layer,r"C:/AR/RadioSignal/MasterLine123.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile",True)
```

This is after first run

[image]

This is after second run.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With your current code, you are writing an application to be launched without QGIS desktop. If you are running your script inside QGIS already, you shouldn't use the `QgsApplication`. Keep only your variable `_writerX` and `_layerX` and remove `QgsApplication`.

```
_layer1 = QgsVectorLayer("/path/to/data.shp", "MASTERLINE", "ogr")

if not _layer1.isValid():
  print("Layer failed to load!")

else:
    print("Layer was loaded successfully!")

_writer1 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_layer1,"/tmp/MasterLine12.shp",'utf-8',QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(),'ESRI Shapefile')
```

Comment: I eventually intend to launch this from command line. That's the reason I used QGSApplication. Is that the reason it is failing?

Comment: I think you need to choose either a QGIS script or the standalone application. Maybe you should add our QgsApplication in a `if` statement.
Is your script working from commandline?